# Check if android app is installed by its url scheme from a web page without opening the app

Tags: javascript, android, url-scheme

I have the url scheme of an android app, which means that when I hit that url from an android device that has that app installed, the app will open up, and when I hit it from an android device that doesn't have it installed, it will go to a "webpage not available" page.

I want to build a javascript function that will check if the app is installed on the device, without opening it, by using the url (testing the url and checking if it should have opened the app or not). 
I tried this but it gives me response status = 0 because it is on another domain.

This is what I used. I will replace my url scheme with "appscheme":

```
function checkUrl() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
return xmlhttp.status;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","appscheme://apps.facebook.com/app",true);
xmlhttp.send();
};
```

I am now returning the response status for the test, but I should give a boolean return according to the response once I figure this out.